# Why can't I select a listbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got this select list configured like this:

[image: select]

Used this code to create it:

```
$('#VSRSelect').empty();
Enumerable.From(self.StaticData.VsrCategories).OrderBy("$.Name.toLowerCase()").ForEach(function(item, index) {
        $('#VSRSelect').append('<option value=' + item.Id + '>' + item.Name + '</option>');
    });
$("#VSRSelect").val(room.VsrcategoryId); // == 12
```

But using `$("#VSRSelect").val(room.VsrcategoryId); // == 12` won't seems to work.
Select list won't show a selected value at all, i'm sure `room.VsrcategoryId` is filled, please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So where are you selecting the val()

Comment: After filling the list, i'll add it to the code.

Comment: The code should work... Does `room.VsrcategoryId.toString()` make any difference? It shouldn't...

Comment: Do you refresh the jQuery Mobile widget after calling `val()`?

Comment: No it shoeldn't, tried it though, still nothing :(

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no, im not touching the widget att all after this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to refresh the ui after setting the value:

```
$("#VSRSelect").val(room.VsrcategoryId).selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: Saved the day, Thanks!!